# google-maps animated symbols (stop the icon after reaching the destination point of the path)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm doing a school project and I'm using the Google Map API for it.
The API is great but I need some help in the code.
After reaching the destination point , I want the icon to stay there and should not repeat the whole path again.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 20.291, lng: 153.027},
  zoom: 6,
  mapTypeId: 'terrain'
});

// Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
// supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
var lineSymbol = {
path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
scale: 8,
strokeColor: '#393'
};

// Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: [{lat: -33.918861, lng: 18.423300}, {lat: -35.842160, lng: 18.863525}, {lat: -39.170387, lng: 35.189209}, {lat: -26.331494, lng: 54.228516}, {lat: 0.462885, lng: 61.083984}, {lat: 19.075984, lng: 72.877656}],
icons: [{
  icon: lineSymbol,
  offset: '100%'
}],
map: map
});

animateCircle(line);
}

// Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
// at fixed intervals.
function animateCircle(line) {
var count = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  count = (count + 1) % 200;

  var icons = line.get('icons');
  icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
  line.set('icons', icons);
}, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the animation when the icon gets to the end of the line.  To stop the `setInterval`, use `clearInterval` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval))

```
function animateCircle(line) {
  var count = 0;
  var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;

    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
    if (count == 199) clearInterval(listener);
  }, 20);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bj0nb70/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
// at fixed intervals.
function animateCircle(line) {
  var count = 0;
  var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;

    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
    if (count == 199) clearInterval(listener);
  }, 20);
}
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 20.291,
      lng: 153.027
    },
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
  // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };

  // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{
      lat: -33.918861,
      lng: 18.423300
    }, {
      lat: -35.842160,
      lng: 18.863525
    }, {
      lat: -39.170387,
      lng: 35.189209
    }, {
      lat: -26.331494,
      lng: 54.228516
    }, {
      lat: 0.462885,
      lng: 61.083984
    }, {
      lat: 19.075984,
      lng: 72.877656
    }],
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(line.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  animateCircle(line);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```